# Archimede's Black Hole

Tags: black-holes

So, I read [Can a black hole be formed by radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14064) and I think I get it. However, I do have a follow-up question. Would it be possible for an interstellar civilization to build huge mirrors around stars to focus enough photons into a small enough space to make a black hole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, using optical means the radiation flux will always be less that that at the source (the star). Because the flux in a star is not concentrated enough to form a black hole, the same is true from any concentrated radiation that you could get by optical means

Comment: Isn't it possible to combine the radiation output of multiple stars into a single point, though?

Comment: no, it would be equivalent to having a star with a larger surface.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how that wouldn't work. Wouldn't it be possible with enough stars to focus enough energy into the point to create a black hole?

Comment: you could do it, but not by purely optical means (that is, mirrors and lenses). I'll try to find you a reference to the theorem

Comment: This question might help http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88821/is-it-possible-to-build-an-optical-system-that-increases-the-perceived-surface-b/189404#189404 and also this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue

Comment: A simple explanation: https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/

You would need to use lasers or some other active means. It's a law of optics that passive mirrors or lenses can never focus something tighter than it was originally focused.